# How to create multiple tables and stored procedures in a single stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that can create multiple tables and stored procedures, but I get a bunch of errors that incorrect syntax near GO

I'm working on a C# method to call the stored procedure.

My stored procedure is something like

```
CreateTables @name nvarchar(500)

declare @query nvarchar(MAX) =

'use db1
 GO

 create table '+@name+'_TableA(column1 int, column2 nvarchar(300)) on [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
 GO

 create table '+@name+'_TableB(column1 nvarchar(500), column2 nvarchar(350)) on [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
 GO

 use db2
 GO

 create table '+@name+'_TableC(column1 int, column2 nvarchar(300)) on [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
 GO

 create table '+@name+'_TableD(column1 nvarchar(500), column2 nvarchar(350)) on [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
 GO

 create procedure '+@name+'_spA @variable1 int, @variable2 nvarchar(300) as
 begin
     insert into tableA..... 
 end
 GO
 ' 

  exec @query
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Alternatively I was thinking of executing every create statement on its own in the stored procedure, but then I need to get the result of each one and save it to a temporal table and then return at the end.

Another route is to hardcode the create statements into my C# and execute each create query from my code, but my ideal solution is to execute everything in a single run of SQL, and get a single result set.

We currently just execute these queries by hand, but we want to automate the process.

Additionally, these are the errors I'm getting

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   ....
>   Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 106
>   'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
>
> Msg 134, Level 15, State 1, Line 122
>   The variable name '@variable1' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Comment: `GO` is a batch separator recognized by SQL tools like SSMS. In this case, remove the GOs from the dynamic SQL batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic queries are treated as single batch, so `GO` is not allowed there, but it conflicts the rule that `CREATE object must be the first statement of batch`.

Trying to use nested EXEC to circumvent the GO problem, if your requirement intends to put everything in a single variable:

```
 declare @v varchar(max) = 
    'EXEC(''CREATE PROC dbo.test_sp1 AS'')
     EXEC(''CREATE PROC dbo.test_sp2 AS'')
    '
 EXEC @v
```